# PHP in $_GET command not working as a string

Tags: php

I have created the following php

```
 <?php
if (isset($_GET["user_name"]) && !empty($_GET["user_name"])) {
        if(strtolower($_GET("user_name")) == "pulkit") {
            echo "Cool You are the Best";
        }
    }

?>

<form action="test1.php" method="GET">
Name: <input type="text" name="user_name"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now when i run the php i get the error :
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\test\test1.php on line 3

Now the thing is the $_GET("user_name") is not giving the result as string.
Why and how to fix it and get the username from the form.
Any help would be apreciated

Comment: `$_GET["user_name"]` not `$_GET("user_name")`. Square brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
if(strtolower($_GET("user_name")) == "pulkit") {
```

to this

```
if(strtolower($_GET["user_name"]) == "pulkit") {
```

its not `$_GET("user_name")` its hase to be `$_GET["user_name"]`

Answer (score 0):

Look your third line you have done a mistake while getting it should be like this

```
if(strtolower($_GET["user_name"]) == "pulkit") {
```